# How do I define the toString in this program. It is supposed to return the super hero based on the favorite color

Tags: java

I need to finish up this programming assignment in 1 hour. I have done most of it, but I cannot understand how to complete the toString at the end. The program is to find a users favorite super hero.

Here is the driver class

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package superherotester;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Charters
 */
public class SuperHeroTester
{
    public static SuperHero aSuperHero;

    /**
     * This program 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        getDataFromUser();
        determineSuperHeroIdentity();
    }

    public static void getDataFromUser()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your first name?");
        String firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your last name?");
        String lastName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your super power?");
        String superPower = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your favorite color?");
        String favoriteColor = keyboard.nextLine();

        aSuperHero = new SuperHero(firstName, lastName, superPower, favoriteColor);

    }

    public static void determineSuperHeroIdentity()
    {
        System.out.println(aSuperHero);

        if (aSuperHero.getFavoriteColor().equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
        {
            System.out.println("You must be Spiderman!");
        }
        else if (aSuperHero.getFavoriteColor().equalsIgnoreCase("green"))
        {
            System.out.println("You must be Green Goblin!");
        }
        else if (aSuperHero.getFavoriteColor().equalsIgnoreCase("black"))
        {
            System.out.println("You must be Batman");
        }
        else if (aSuperHero.getFavoriteColor().equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
        {
            System.out.println("You must be Captain America");
        }
        else if (aSuperHero.getFavoriteColor().equalsIgnoreCase("purple"))
        {
            System.out.println("You must be Magneto");
        }

    }

}
```

and here is the Domain Class that i need to finish. The tostring is at the end of this domain class.

```
/*
 * Describe what this program does.
 */
package superherotester;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class SuperHero
{
   //define your attributes here:
String firstName;
String lastName;
String superPower;
String favColor;


    //define your constructor here:
public SuperHero(String firstName, String lastName, String superPower, String favColor)

{
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
this.superPower = superPower;
this.favColor = favColor;
}    

    //define your setters and getters here:

public String getfirstName()
{
return firstName;
}
public String getlastName()
{
return lastName;
}
public String getsuperPower()
{
return superPower;
}
public String getfavColor()
{
return favColor;
}


public void setfirstName(String aFirstName)
{
    firstName = aFirstName;
}

public void setlastName(String aLastName)
{
    lastName = aLastName;
}

public void setsuperPower(String aSuperPower)
{
    superPower = aSuperPower;
}

public void setfavColor(String aFavColor)
{
    favColor = aFavColor;
}   
    //define your toString here:



}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaken on what `toString()` is supposed to do.

> How do I define the toString in this program. It is supposed to return the super hero based on the favorite color

The toString() method has nothing to do with searching for a superhero.

> The program is to find a users favorite super hero.

Yes, the program is to do this, but again toString() has nothing to do with this.

---

Instead `toString()` is supposed to return a String representation of a SuperHero object, no more and no less. Likely it will output a String that holds the contents of the key fields of the class:

```
String firstName;
String lastName;
String superPower;
String favColor;
```

and that's it.

Myself, I'd create a StringBuilder object and then append the variable name followed by the variable state, and then return the `toString()` from the StringBuilder.

Comment: How do i do that? I am very new to java. This is a introductory course.

Comment: While using the StringBuilder class is preferable for almost any production-ready code, it's probably okay to use basic string concatenation at your level of school. Something like `firstName + " " + lastName + " uses " + superPower + " and wears a lot of " + favColor + "."` That said, definitely look at the StringBuilder class and try using it in your next project.

Comment: @user315819: just look at what James Collier and James Tanner posted. 1+ to their answers. And then up-vote their answers if they helped.

Answer (score 1):

ToString functions for classes concatenates the fields of the class into a usable format. Since you didn't provide a format, I took some creative liberties:

```
public String toString() {
   return "My super hero name is " + firstName + " " + lastName + "! I have the amazing power of " + superPower + ", neat huh? Also, my favorite color is" + favColor + ".";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. That was very simple, but i doesn't run. Can you load this up and help me debug it?

Comment: @user315819: Please don't do that. Try to debug yourself, that's how you learn. Then if stuck, ask a new question, but don't just ask others to do your work.

Comment: Time is running out. :(

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Hovercraft Full Of Eels.  For homework, an in-person tutor might be helpful if you're really stuck, but in the field you'll need to become proficient and Googling and finding your own answers.

Comment: @user315819: on this site, your time constraints are not our issue. It's harsh but a reality. If you need serious help though at least post the error your getting. The easier you make it for someone to answer your questions the better the answers you'll see. Also don't forget to up-vote this answer, since I'm the only one who's upvoted it so far.

Comment: I up voted it. It wont run. The superhero in public class SuperHero keep saying the drive does not exist. "class SuperHero is public, should be declared in a file named SuperHero.java"

Comment: @user315819: then do that -- put it in its own file. The error message is telling you *exactly* what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a function that overrides the [Object.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method.

So, you have to add a toString method to your class that returns some string representation for that object. Something like this:

```
public String toString(){
   // Return some string representation of the object
   return firstName + " " + lastName + " loves " + favColor;
}
```

What that string representation is depends what you'll use it for.

Comment: It wont run. The superhero in public class SuperHero keep saying the drive does not exist. "class SuperHero is public, should be declared in a file named SuperHero.java"

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem you asked. But, yes, classes should be declared in a file with the same name.